# Are there good resources for interpreting linux performance counters?

Tags: linux, performance, linux-kernel, performancecounter

Are there resources that explain the meaning of the events listed by `perf list`, and how to interpret them ?

Comment: Some more contextual information: I'm investigating a CPU scalability issue. I did several runs changing the number of CPUs used using `taskset` and tracing all hardware, software and cache events with `perf trace`. I can see some counters are linear, and some are not, like `branch-loads` or `dTLB-stores`, which could explain my issue, but I don't really know how to interpret it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check

**Table 19-2.  Non-Architectural Performance Events In the Processor Core of Next Generation Intel Core i7, i5, i3 Processors** in this doc

http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/253669.pdf

This lists all the events and their meanings for intel systems. Also check the man page for [perf list](http://linux.die.net/man/1/perf-list)